# Need to filter data for previous month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently explicitly setting a date filter in my query to get returns within a certain time period. I need to change this to start at the first day and end at the last day of the previous month. The column I am filtering on is trade_date. My current code is

'''

```
WHERE

            trade_date >= '01-SEP-20'
            AND trade_date <= '30-JUL-21'
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
WHERE trade_date >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MM')
  AND trade_date <= LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1));
```